# Zend OPcache requires Zend Engine API version 220090626

Tags: debian, plesk, opcache

I made an update of php 5.3 to 5.4 under Debian Squeeze. After that I try to install OPcache, that's what I have done:

```
apt-get install build-essential php5-dev unzip
cd /usr/src
wget https://github.com/zend-dev/ZendOptimizerPlus/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd /usr/src/ZendOptimizerPlus-master
phpize
./configure
make
make test
make install

vi /etc/php5/conf.d/opcache.ini


;zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/opcache.so ;PHP 5.4 can't use this, file not exist on my server
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/opcache.so ;PHP 5.3 got only this one (?)
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=8000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

php -v
Zend OPcache requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Zend Technologies at http://www.zend.com/ for a later version of Zend OPcache.

PHP 5.4.31-1~dotdeb.0 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2014 18:40:42)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

What have I done wrong? "phpize" gives me this:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

Shouldn't this be: 20100525 with PHP 5.4?

Help pls!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that you are making is to do a default `./configure`  you should have `--enable-opcache` of course, but you also need to specify a `--with-php-config=.../php-config` where `...` denotes the path to the 5.4 php-config.

Comment: there is only /usr/bin/php-config which returns older 5.3.10 and symlink /usr/bin/php-config5 -> /etc/alternatives/php-config which is the same. ... php -v returns version 5.4.3

Comment: Not if you are a php developer who is testing across  all current versions or even a sysadmin who is offering 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6, say